# SVG not rendering complete text

Tags: html, css, svg

Text not being rendered completely and is cut on left and right side.

```html
<svg version="1.2" id="Layer_1" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 802 702" style="enable-background:new 0 0 742 702; width: 100%;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="title_1_">
      <path id="SVGID_x5F_1_x5F_" class="st3" d="M206.4,101.3c0,0,48.1-39.8,149-39.8c87.3,0,141.7,40.8,141.7,40.8"></path>
      <text text="" x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle">
        <textPath xlink:href="#SVGID_x5F_1_x5F_" startOffset="155">
          <tspan style="font-family:'OpenSans-Bold'; font-size:19px;  letter-spacing:1px;" class="text-fix-large">WELCOME TO WORLD OF PROGRAMMING</tspan>
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How would you like this to be solved? Write a shorter text, decrease font size, or increase path length?

Comment: @Mehdi I am trying to increase the path length. but unable to understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The path is defined as a Bézier curve, [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#b%C3%A9zier_curves) provides a good explanation about the corresponding syntax.

One way to increase the path length is to update the coordinates of the path points and curve control points.

A second, probably easier solution is to:

- add a `scale` SVG `transform` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#scale)) to the path
- update the textPath's `startOffset` value accordingly.

In the example below, path is scaled by 1.5, and `startOffset` set to 155 * 1.5.

```html
<svg version="1.2" id="Layer_1" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 802 702" style="enable-background:new 0 0 742 702; width: 100%;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="title_1_">
      <path id="SVGID_x5F_1_x5F_" transform="scale(1.5)" class="st3" d="M206.4,101.3c0,0,48.1-39.8,149-39.8c87.3,0,141.7,40.8,141.7,40.8"></path>
      <text text="" x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle">
        <textPath xlink:href="#SVGID_x5F_1_x5F_" startOffset="232.5">
          <tspan style="font-family:'OpenSans-Bold'; font-size:19px;  letter-spacing:1px;" class="text-fix-large">WELCOME TO WORLD OF PROGRAMMING</tspan>
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Will need to update the path. Will go through the Beizer Curve doc. Any tool that I can use to build the path?

Comment: The scale method provides a similar result, as shown in the demo. Why not go for it?

Comment: for single d-path editing use: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/